# markdown -> pandoc -> PDF | chokes on rendering tables

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, xelatex

I am using Pandoc to generate a PDF from markdown, but am having trouble producing a table.  The terminal command used is:

```
$ pandoc -s -o foo.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex --filter pandoc-citeproc bar.md
```

The grid table used in my markdown document looks like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
|               |               | - bright color     |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
|               |               | - tasty            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I've tried switching the LaTeX engine, using different forms of markdown tables, everything I can think of.  Infuriatingly, I got this to work *once* and have spent the past few hours trying to reproduce the results, but with no success.  Instead, I just keep getting the following error message:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Undefined control sequence.
\y ->\LT@array 

l.7128 }{}
```

Any ideas?  I'm using Pandoc v. 1.12.0.2.

Comment: Your table snippet renders properly using Pandoc 1.11.1 on Ubuntu with TeX Live. The `--filter` option doesn't seem to be available for this version of Pandoc, so I removed that from the command.

Comment: @gwijthoff This table also renders well with pandoc 1.12.3.1 . Put some more details in the question please.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, just updated to pandoc 1.12.3, and am still having the same problem. With a markdown file containing nothing but the simple grid table above, the command `pandoc -o testing.pdf testing.md` gives me the exact same error message above.  What else would be helpful to know?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a Pandoc issue per se. The error you are getting is a TeX error and what it says is that your TeX interpreter doesn't recognize the `longtable` environment. Maybe you are using a document class that doesn't use the `longtable`package by default...

If you are using a tex template, try to add the `longtable` package manually:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

This must be added right after the line that defines the document class:

```
\documentclass[some options]{some class}
```

This will solve the current issue, although TeX may then complain about other stuff.

By the way, you might be better off asking this kind of question on [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).